# angular-ui-router shares state between multiple tabs in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using $stateProvider to manage states using ui-router ~0.2.15
The problem is that when I open app in two or more windows/tabs
in the same browser the state is shared between them, i.e.
navbar and view are changed in all those tabs/windows.

Do you know how to overcome this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ui-router is capable of this.
Are you sure you are not using BrowserSync or something like this?
Try to access your webapp in multiple browsers if it's synced and you have something like this then you definitely use something to sync your tabs.
If you generated your app with fountainjs or something like that then it's certainly installed. if you have a package.json or something similar please attach it.

---

**EDIT**

Access the BrowserSync UI ([default port 3001 or 8080](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-ui)), access `/sync-options` and disable all the options not related to `CodeSync`, see attached : [browser sync menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdHkT.png)

Comment: I am in fact using browser sync. But the code is not changed in the middle of using the app when this happens. I don't think browser sync should cause it.

Answer (score 0):

**gulp/server.js**:

```
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init(files, {
    startPath: '/',

    ghostMode:false, // do ghost mode disabled.

    server: {
        baseDir: baseDir,
        middleware: middleware,
        routes: routes
    },
    browser: browser
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).